# Java try-with-recourses stuck

Tags: java, sockets, try-with-resources

I have a classic server-multi-clients program. Tthe server listens to ServerSocket and for each incoming socket it builds a new Runnable class and executes it in ExecuteService.

In the run method of the Runnable class, I open try-with-resources block and in the try I have a while loop that reads from inputstream and writes to outputstream until it receives FIN command from the clients. Everything works fine and the clients disconnect successfully. The run reaches the finally block and prints some stuff for testing, but it doesn't exit the try block so it does not exit the run method and I am stuck in the run somewhere, maybe the read method of the inputstream.

I can post the code if anyone interested.

How can I force close everything in the finally and exit the run method?

The code:
Server.java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    playersReady = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ServerSocket server = null;
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(Consts.PORT);
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(characters.size());
        while(playersReady.size()<characters.size()){
            RequestHandler handler = new RequestHandler(server.accept());
            service.execute(handler);
        }
        service.shutdownNow();
        service.shutdown();
        while(!service.isTerminated()){}

        System.out.println("finished");
```

---

RequestHandler.java

```
public final class RequestHandler implements Runnable {

    .....

public void run() {
    //DataOutputStream output = null;
    //DataInputStream input = null;

    try (DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())){
        // socket.setSoTimeout(500);
        handleReady(input.readUTF().split(" "), output);
        while (/*!shutdown && !socket.isClosed() && */socket.isConnected()) {

            System.out.println("check before read " + character.getId());
            String request = input.readUTF();
            System.out.println("check after read " + character.getId());

            System.out.println("-----------------------------------" + request);
            if (shutdown) {
                socket.shutdownInput();
                socket.getOutputStream().flush();
                socket.shutdownOutput();
                break;
            }
            String[] requestParser = request.split(" ");
            if (requestParser[1].equals("DMG")) {
                // handle damage request
                handleDamage(requestParser, output);
            } else if (requestParser[1].equals("BND")) {
                // handle bandage request
                handleBandage(requestParser, output);
            } else if (requestParser[1].equals("FIN")) {
                // handle finish request
                handleFin();
                if (!socket.isClosed())
                    socket.shutdownInput();
                if (!socket.isClosed()) {
                    socket.getOutputStream().flush();
                    socket.shutdownOutput();
                }
                shutdown = true;
                break;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        shutdown = true;
        break;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            System.out.println("finished");

            if (!socket.isClosed())
                socket.shutdownInput();
            if (!socket.isClosed()) {
                socket.getOutputStream().flush();
                socket.shutdownOutput();
                socket.close();
            }
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Done run");
}
```

....

---

The `System.out.println("finished")` in the finally is printed,
but the `System.out.println("Done run")` in the end of the run method does not!!

Why?
It stuck in the run method, I think in the readUTF call, but I closed all the resources!

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program? Your "I think in the readUTF call" is a bit vague.

Comment: I tried, nothing special, it passes the run method and goes up to the Runnable class of java and stops but the threads continues to run

Answer (score 3):

You return before that line, that's why it is not run. The finally block is run anyway, because *it is a finally block*. Finally blocks are always run, there is only one exception from this rule: `System.exit()`, but this is not the case.

Comment: What line? The run method runs perfectly, it just doesn't stop, and doesn't stop the associated thread

Comment: Oh I see, I changed every "return" statement to "break".  It now prints the final print command but the thread doesn't stop, I mean it doesn't continue the Server's run method